# javascript both event firing at same time for gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` in which there are 2 columns such as `Status` and `View`

and below is my js code:-

```
function UltraWebGrid1_Select(sender, records) {
        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            var record = records[i];
            if (record.Status == "Status") {
                window.open('FrmInwardNextAction.aspx?Inward_Mkey=' + record.mkey + "&View=N&Status=" + record.Status + "&IWNO=" + record.Doc_No, '_blank', 'height=670,width=1000,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,scrollbars=yes');
            }
            if (record.View == "View") {
                window.open('InwardDocDetails.aspx?Key=' + record.mkey + "&View=Y&Status=" + record.Status + "&IWNO=" + record.Doc_No, '_blank', 'height=700,width=1020,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,scrollbars=yes'); //obout grid
            } 
        }
    }
```

Currently, If I click on `Status` my both links of `Status` as well as `View` page is opening at the same time.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdyfyxtr/) for more details.

**UPDATE**

Source code HTML of the gridview in the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdyfyxtr/1/)

Comment: Provided fiddle not working.

Comment: @RohanVeer: its not pure html that it will work, I just added that for reference purpose.

Comment: @RohanVeer: See my updated part of the question for more info.

Comment: In record you are picking the grid row and every row contains Status and View in the column. So your both if condition is always true. Please check that.

Comment: @SainPradeep: yes, I get both status and view in `record` but what I want is, when I click on status only status value should fire and when i click on view, only view value should fire..

Comment: When does `UltraWebGrid1_Select` fire? it appears to fire on row selection. The function itself implies a loop through all records, but assuming it's just the record for the row, you do not differentiate the source of the click. You have 2 distinct `if` statements which appear to always be true for both cases so both `open` commands will fire.  It appears to me that you are assuming that selecting a row is the same as selecting individual cells.  Just because the mouse pointer is over the words "Status" or "View" does not mean you set a click handler .

Comment: I think you should look at sender parameter. What does it represent? Maybe its the cell you click on?

Comment: @Lesmian: are you their ? only you can resolve my obout issue. As you have idea about it. If u r free, then let me know.

Comment: @Lesmian: If possible, Please come here on chat, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120475/grid-discussion

Comment: Please give me your data (records). If you have item in records which have Status value == "Status" and View value == "View" of course the both of if block will be executed!

Answer (score 0):

On the second condition 
`if (record.View == "View") {
                window.open('InwardDocDetails.aspx?Key=' + record.mkey + "&View=Y&Status=" + record.Status + "&IWNO=" + record.Doc_No, '_blank', 'height=700,width=1020,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,scrollbars=yes');}`

you should replace `record.Status` by `record.View`

Answer (score 0):

You can try if ..else if condition

```
if (record.Status == "Status") 
{
    window.open('FrmInwardNextAction.aspx?Inward_Mkey=' + record.mkey + "&View=N&Status=" + record.Status + "&IWNO=" + record.Doc_No, '_blank', 'height=670,width=1000,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,scrollbars=yes');
}
else if (record.View == "View") 
{
    window.open('InwardDocDetails.aspx?Key=' + record.mkey + "&View=Y&Status=" + record.Status + "&IWNO=" + record.Doc_No, '_blank', 'height=700,width=1020,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,scrollbars=yes'); //obout grid
}
```

the second condition can be change to else if .. then only one code will work at atime .